# Confidence interval for odds ratio with differents results

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, categorical-data, estimation, odds-ratio

> Find the confidence interval for the odds ratio, where
>   $OR=e^{\hat{B_1}}=3.5701$, $\hat{B_1}=1.2726$,
>   $\sigma(\hat{B_1})=0.5016$ with 95% confidence.

First I followed the idea from notes that I found
$$CI(\hat{B_1},0.95)=\hat{B_1}\pm1.96\sigma(\hat{B_1})=(0.2894;2.2557)$$
then
$$CI(OR,0.95)=(e^{0.2894};e^{2.2557})=(1.3356;9.5420)$$
But in some other notes they solve it with delta method.

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $F(X)\sim N(F(\mu),\sigma^2[F'(\mu)]^2)$ , as
$$F(\mu)=F(\hat{B_1})=3.5701$$
$$\sigma^2=(0.5016)^2=0.2516$$
$$[F'(\mu)]^2=[e^{\hat{B_1}}]^2=e^{2\hat{B_1}}=12.7458\rightarrow \sigma^2[F'(\mu)]^2=3.2068$$
thus
$$e^{\hat{B_1}}\sim N(3.5071;3.2068)$$
$$CI(e^{\hat{B_1}},0.95)=3.5701\pm 1.96\sqrt{3.2068}=(0.0602;7.08)$$

The results are different, what is the right method?

Comment: The delta method is an asymptotic argument, and I don't think it applies here.

Comment: @Greenparker The first method is fine? I've seen the delta method for odds ratio in "Categorical Data Analysis, Alan Agresti", but I don't understand it well.